# IComparer interface, compare many objects not just two instances

Tags: c#

I'm following examples Apress pro c# framework and I have question on IComparer interface
If I want to create some custom comparer which will compare my objects by name I should implement IComparer interface so I have following

```
public class CarNameComparer : IComparer
    {
        int IComparer.Compare(object obj1, object obj2)
        {
            Car temp1 = obj1 as Car;
            Car temp2 = obj2 as Car;
            if (temp1 != null && temp2 != null)
            {
                return String.Compare(temp1.Name, temp2.Name);                
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Parameter is not a Car");
            }
        }
    }
```

And I'm calling to compare like this

```
Array.Sort(italianCars, new CarNameComparer());
```

Which is fine, but this approach is comparing only two instances, as far as I can see this is a limited usage. What if I want to compare bunch of objects, not just two of them ?

Comment: Have you investigated using IComparable and IComparable<T>?

Comment: Do consider to make `Comparer<Car>` the base class of your `CarNameComparer`. Your method then implements an abstract method with strongly typed arguments. The base class will take care of the cases where the objects are not `Car`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the use of the Comparer. It will still sort the array even if there are a thousand instances of `Car`. It just does it by comparing *two at a time*!

Comment: aha, it uses as obj1 and obj2 objects from italianCars array and sort them. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Jamiec answer, you can sort the array using LINQ -

```
italianCars.OrderBy(car => car.Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help [How to use the IComparable and IComparer interfaces in Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320727)